# How do I upload a pdf to Sitecore Media Library via Sitecore.Services.Client Restful API service

Tags: ssc

I am using the following to Create an item, and it works to create a folder in the media library, but I want to create/upload a pdf using this or a similar technique. Here is my code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    var authUrl = "https://mysitecoresite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login";
    var authData = new Authentication
    {
        Domain = "sitecore",
        Username = "admin",
        Password = "b"
    };

    var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authUrl);

    authRequest.Method = "POST";
    authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

    var requestAuthBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authData);

    var authDatas = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestAuthBody);

    using (var dataStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(authDatas, 0, authDatas.Length);
    }
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    authRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    // System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
    var authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Login Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)authResponse).StatusDescription}");


    authResponse.Close();

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf");
    HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    
    Stream mediaStream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
    string itemName = "Test PDF";
    string mediaFileExt = ".pdf";

    var emailObj = new ItemRequest
    {
        ItemName = "PtrTest2",
        TemplateID = "{FE5DD826-48C6-436D-B87A-7C4210C7413B}",
        Title = "Class List Test June",
        Text = "Class List Test June 2020",
        Media = mediaStream
            

    };
    var url = "https://mysitecoresite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2FMedia%20library";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;

    var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailObj);

    var data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestBody);

    using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    // var response = request.GetResponse();

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Item Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription}");
    }    
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred. Message: {ex.Message}.\r\n StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}.\r\n InnerException: {ex.InnerException}");
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                .ReadToEnd());
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Note: I really just need to know what field the actual PDF body should be mapped to.

Comment: Hi Paul, follow this article, in this article you can see how to create media item programmatically so that from this you can take some help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732440/in-sitecore-7-5-how-to-programmatically-create-media-items-with-language-version

Comment: Thank you, I will review. I know I am just about there. Best Regards,

Comment: Have you considered using SPE remoting? Would allow you to upload through PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I really just need to know what field the actual PDF body should
> be mapped to.

The actual field name that holds the file data is the **Blob** field. The type of this field is **Attachment**. The name **Media** is just the field title or similar to display name.

The template where this field resides can be found at `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I saw that field ... this is so helpful. I have been trying to figure this out for a while. I will let you know.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, as per the question you posted, did my answer help? If so, please mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't worked on this yet. I am hopeful that this will resolve my issue and once I have confirmed this, I will be certain to mark the answer. I always do and I always appreciate the advice.

Comment: Nice.. Thanks !

Comment: Well, I am still having issues trying to figure how to link the pdf. Sitecore Blob brings up Azure.